# "peel off" vs "chip off"

Tags: difference

Peel off vs chip off any difference?

I checked the Internet, but it doesn't seem to have the answer.

Comment: You peel off a layer like the skin of a fruit, or paint. You chip off a piece of something, like stone or wood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Peel* means to remove the surface or skin of something.  An orange is peeled, or your skin can be peeling.

*Chip* means for a small area or volume of something to break off.

Something that is chipped will always be solid/hard.

Peeling can apply to something solid/hard like dried paint, or soft like skin.